# How can I access/import Android Platform APIs with Typescript?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am currently building an App with Ionic. To be able to create App Bundles bigger than 150 MB I want to use Play Asset Delivery. I already [build](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery/build-native-java) it and the next step is to [integrate (install time)](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-java#install-time-delivery) it.

**Content of the second URL:** To integrate it first a [Context object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)) is received via `createPackageContext()` and then the context object method `getAssets()` is used to get an [AssetManager instance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager). The AssetManager instance Method `call()` is used afterwards to finally access the assets.

The Problem is that I am working with Typescript files and I don't know how to import the Android Platform APIs that I need. It seems like I need to import `android.content.res.AssetManager` and      `android.content.Context` to access the methods from above.

Modules are usually imported like this: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` Import the BrowserModule form folder @angular/platform-brwoser. The module folders are inside my Ionic project node_modules directory. Many modules are already installed and some can be installed via `npm` in the CLI.

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
NodeJS            : v12.18.3
npm               : 6.14.6
OS                : Windows 10
Gradle            : 6.6.1
Ionic Framework   : @ionic/angular 5.3.3
Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
```

Do you know how to import the required android platform APIs or did I do something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic Framework works on top of a webview, packed into a binary app package. So typescript gets transpiled to JavaScript and packaged-in to be parsed and interpreted by the browser (webview).

In order to access native APIs you need to write a plugin and expose native functionality to your TS code that way.

For example, if your hybrid application uses Capacitor from Ionic Team:
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/android

If you are using Cordova:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/

In case you are leveraging popular native APIs there is a chance someone already did the job and you just need to find the plugin.